# KafkaProducer08 in Flink exception

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am implementing a platform with Apache Flink + Kafka. I get the following error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.SchemaException: Error reading field 'responses': Error reading array of size 4416367, only 265 bytes available
    at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.Schema.read(Schema.java:71)
```

What is the source of this error?

What is the solution?

Where can I find more logs or do something to get additional debug info?

Thank you

Comment: What kind of schema are you using for writing and reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the source of this error?

It seems that the data has been serialized differently than you are trying to deserialize it.

> What is the solution?

Ensure that the data is being serialized and deserialized using the same code on both ends. I suspect that there's a version or schema mismatch.

> Where can I find more logs or do something to get additional debug info?

Flink's TaskManagers, running the Kafka Consumer will log information regarding the read process.